# vue.js: can't access to router parameters from computed property

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to pass a string parameter using the link. but it seems that computed or methods property cannot return the parameter value. The whole component stops rendering when I use computed property.

If I directly put `{{ $route.params.**** }}` on the template, everything works fine. But that's not the way I want.

```
<template>
  <div class="container my-5 py-5">
    <div class="row">{{ category }}</div>

    <!-- <div class="row">{{ $route.params.category }}</div> -->
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "shops",
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    category: () => {
      return this.$route.params.category;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

from router.js file:

```
   {
      path: "/:category",
      name: "category",
      props: true,
      component: () => import("./views/Shops.vue")
    },
```

I did't get any error message in the console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are facing this `error` because an arrow function wouldn't bind `this` to the `vue` instance for which you are defining the `computed` property. The same would happen if you were to define `methods` using an `arrow` function.

Don't use arrow functions to define methods/computed properties, `this` will not work.

Just replace

```
        category: () => {
            return this.$route.params.category;
        }
```

With:

```
        category() {
            return this.$route.params.category;
        }
```

Refer - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

Answer (score 4):

Try with

```
category(){
  return this.$route.params.category;
}
```

or

```
category: function() {
  return this.$route.params.category;
}
```

`this` is not the same in arrow functions than in plain functions: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26